# Jmeter postProcessor to be executed only once after all the http requests are complete

Tags: testing, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

[image]

here the postRequest http request executes in a loop, but i want the post processor to execute only after all the http request loop is complete. How to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter PostProcessors obey [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), in your setup JSR223 PostProcessor will be executed after **each sampler** in your Test Plan.

So if you want to get a message in the log file once HTTP Request loop is finished - convert the JSR223 PostProcessor into [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler).

If you don't want the JSR223 Sampler to appear in your Test Results - add the next line to it:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()
```

Comment: But we can't add the samplers with out a thread group, so you want me to create another thread group and add jsr223 sampler in it. Is this the only optimal way

Comment: If you want to execute something after a Thread Group - it's better to put it inside [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

Comment: @DmitriT Thank you! Your comment should be the accepted answer. I use it to play a sound when all requests are finished, so I know when to check the results